# Scala Macros: "cannot create TypeTag from a type T having unresolved type parameters"

Tags: scala, macros

I'm playing around with Scalas new macros and found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/3388753) from [akshaal](https://gist.github.com/akshaal). As it seams I did not quite get it. 
Given the following trait (the fieldsMacro is more or less the same as in akshaal example)

```
case class Field[I <: AnyRef](name: String, get: I => Any)

type Fields[I <: AnyRef] = List[Field[I]]

trait FieldAccess {
import FieldMacors._
    import Field._
    import language.experimental.macros

    def fields[T <: AnyRef]: Fields[T] = macro fieldsMacro[T]

    def field[T <: AnyRef](name: String): Fields[T] = fields[T].headOption <-- does not work!
                                                             ^
}
 object FieldMacors {

import language.experimental.macros
import Field._

def fields[T <: AnyRef]: Fields[T] = macro fieldsMacro[T]

/**
 * Get a list of fiels
 */
def fieldsMacro[T <: AnyRef: c.TypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Fields[T]] = {
  import c.universe._
  val instanceT = c.typeOf[T]

  val fields = instanceT.members.filter(member => member.isTerm && !member.isMethod)

  // transform an iterable of expr in a expr of list.
  def foldIntoListExpr[T: c.TypeTag](exprs: Iterable[c.Expr[T]]): c.Expr[List[T]] =
    exprs.foldLeft(reify { Nil: List[T] }) {
      (accumExpr, expr) =>
        reify { expr.splice :: accumExpr.splice }
    }

  val fieldAccessores = for (field <- fields) yield {
    val name = field.name.toString.trim // Why is there a space at the end of field name?!
    val nameExpr = c literal name

    // Construct expression (x : $I) => x.$name
    val getFunArgTree = ValDef(Modifiers(), newTermName("x"), TypeTree(instanceT), EmptyTree)
    val getFunBodyTree = Select(Ident(newTermName("x")), newTermName(name))
    val getFunExpr = c.Expr[T => Any](Function(List(getFunArgTree), getFunBodyTree))
    reify {
      Field[T](name = nameExpr.splice, get = getFunExpr.splice)
    }
  }
  foldIntoListExpr(fieldAccessores)
}
}
```

the compiler complains about
'Cannot create TypeTag from a type T having unresolved type parameters'

How do I manage to get the T to the macro or must I implement another macro that uses the fieldsMacro

Comment: It's hard to say anything without seeing the code of the macro. I'd guess though that you're using a c.TypeTag context bound instead of c.AbsTypeTag.

Comment: Yes. in def fieldsMacro[T <: AnyRef: c.TypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Fields[T]] I'm using the TypeTag. Why and how should I use the AbsTypeTag?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`T: TypeTag` context bound for a type parameter `T` means that you require type arguments provided in place of this parameter to be concrete (i.e. not contain references to untagged type parameters or abstract type members). Otherwise an error occurs.

Examples:

```
scala> val ru = scala.reflect.runtime.universe
ru @ 6d657803: scala.reflect.api.JavaUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.JavaUniverse@6d657803

scala> def foo[T: ru.TypeTag] = implicitly[ru.TypeTag[T]]
foo: [T](implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]

scala> foo[Int]
res0 @ 7eeb8007: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int] = TypeTag[Int]

scala> foo[List[Int]]
res1 @ 7d53ccbe: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[Int]] = TypeTag[scala.List[Int]]

scala> def bar[T] = foo[T] // T is not a concrete type here, hence the error
<console>:26: error: No TypeTag available for T
       def bar[T] = foo[T]
                       ^

scala> def bar[T] = foo[List[T]] // T being not concrete renders 
                                 // the entire compound type not concrete
<console>:26: error: No TypeTag available for List[T]
       def bar[T] = foo[List[T]]
                       ^

scala> def bar[T: TypeTag] = foo[T] // to the contrast T is concrete here
                                    // because it's bound by a concrete tag bound
bar: [T](implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]

scala> bar[Int]
res2 @ 7eeb8007: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[Int] = TypeTag[Int]

scala> def bar[T: TypeTag] = foo[List[T]]
bar: [T](implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[T]]

scala> bar[Int]
res3 @ 1a108c98: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[Int]] = TypeTag[scala.List[Int]]

scala> bar[List[Int]]
res4 @ 76d5989c: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[List[Int]]] = TypeTag[scala.List[scala.List[Int]]]
```

Having a notion of concrete types to be enforcible at compile-time is useful. Having concrete type tags on by default is useful as well as described in https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-5884.

However as you've seen yourself, concrete type tags in macros can be a source of confusion, because typically macros should work both for concrete and non-concrete types. Therefore one should always use `c.AbsTypeTag` instead. Due to this reason we no longer allow `c.TypeTag` context bounds in 2.10.0-M7: https://github.com/scala/scala/commit/788478d3ab.

**Edit**. In 2.10.0-RC1 some `AbsTypeTag` has been renamed to `WeakTypeTag`. Everything else about type tags remains the same.

Comment: Thanks. I migrated to the 7th milestone and now it works. The link to the git change set was of great help.