# Scala, String representation of a function

Tags: string, function, scala, representation

is there a way where I can get the string representation of a function?

`val f = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 66, 11).foldLeft(55)_`

`f` is a function of type `((Int, Int) => Int) => Int`, and that would be the representation I am looking for, but I can't find it anywhere.

the `toString` method was my first try, of course, but all it returns is `<function1>`. scala REPL does it right, and the Documentation too. There must be a way?

Regards.

Comment: Are you looking for the string representation of a function or the string representation of the type of a function?

Comment: The type, I'd guess. The string must be something like ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int

Comment: I believe this is how REPL does that: [`TypeStrings`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/master/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/TypeStrings.scala)

Comment: That's pretty much overkill. sschaef's answer was pretty what I wanted!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the type is known at compile time, you can use Scalas `TypeTag`:

```
scala> import reflect.runtime.universe._
import reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def typeRep[A : TypeTag](a: A) = typeOf[A]
typeRep: [A](a: A)(implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[A])reflect.runtime.universe.Type

scala> val f = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 66, 11).foldLeft(55)_
f: ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int = <function1>

scala> typeRep(f)
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = ((Int, Int) => Int) => Int
```

For a detailed description on what `TypeTag` is doing see [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it/12232195#12232195) answer.

Comment: Okay, this does pretty much what I want, thank you! It seems a little bit "much" though. I guess there isn't an easier way, right? (questions arise like What's TypeTag?)

Comment: I gave you a link to another answer on SO, explaining what TypeTag is doing. Reflection is the easiest way to achieve what you want, I think.