# Require Type to be Instantiatable, ie not a trait/abstract

Tags: scala, mixins

Say I have:

```
trait A

class B extends A

class C extends A
```

Is there a way to configure type parameters such that:

```
class Foo[AType <: A with canCreateInstance]
    def newAType : AType = new AType
```

The idea is that Foo would only be able to take classes that implement A, like B or C, but not A itself.

Comment: Imho the most common way to achieve this is not to require that a type can be instantiated but to use factories instead. For instance, you could pass a factory to the constructor of `Foo` which can be used to construct new `A`s within `Foo`. This simplifies the design since you do not have to care about whether `A` is abstract or some instantiable subtype of `A`, all you need to know is how to construct it.

Comment: @ultramiraculous -- It is not possible to do exactly what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the trait a companion object. The companion object would be the one returning the instances of `AType`.

For a use of companion object:

```
trait Queue[T]{
    def head:T
    def tail:Queue[T]
    def enqueue(x:T):Queue[T]
}

object Queue{
    def apply[T](xs: T*): Queue[T] = 
        new QueueImpl[T](xs.toList)

    private class QueueImpl[T](
        private val leading:List[T],
        private val trailing:List[T]=Nil
    ) extends Queue[T]
    {
       // methods in here
    }
}
```

Maybe this is simpler:

```
object A{

  def aType(...):A = new B(...)

  def aType(...):A = new C(...)


  /* classes */

  private class C(...) extends A

  private class B(...) extends A{
    // blah blah
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to create instances of a given type is to use a factory style as @bluenote10 mentioned in the comments.

To do that we first create a factory definition

```
// factory definition
trait CanCreateInstance[T] {
  def create: T
}
```

Then, in our class we ask for a factory of that given type

```
class Foo[T <: A](implicit factory: CanCreateInstance[T]) {
  def newT: T = factory.create
}
```

We can add some default factories to the companion object of `CanCreateInstance`

```
object CanCreateInstance {
  // define default availble instance creators
  implicit def bFactory = new CanCreateInstance[B] {
    def create = new B
  }
}
```

Then we can simply use it like this

```
val fooB = new Foo[B]
val newB = fooB.newT
```

If we needed `Foo` to be able to create an instance of another type, we could simply supply a factory.

```
implicit val cFactory = new CanCreateInstance[C] {
  def create = new C
}

val fooC = new Foo[C]
val newC = fooC.newT
```

This construct allows any user of `Foo` to supply a factory if a default factory is not available. You could for instance supply a factory for `A` as well

```
implicit val aFactory = new CanCreateInstance[A] {
  def create = new A {}
}
```

If you need to create instance from an unknown type at runtime without creating a factory you need to dive into `TypeTag`. Information about that can be found here: [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it)