# Checking if a partial function in scala is definied for a value with unknow type

Tags: scala, type-erasure, higher-rank-types, partialfunction

I have the following trait (to get kind of rank 2 polymorphism [click](http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2010/07/02/higher-rank-polymorphism-in-scala/))

```
type Id[A] = A
trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] {
def apply[A](a: F[A]): G[A]
def isDefinedAt[A](a: A): Boolean}
```

And a function to transform a partial function to this trait:

```
implicit def pft[B: ClassTag](f: PartialFunction[B, B])= new (Id ~> Id) {
def apply[A](a: A): A = f(a.asInstanceOf[B]).asInstanceOf[A]
def isDefinedAt[A: ClassTag](a: A)(implicit ev2: ClassTag[A]) : Boolean = /*type check*/
               f.isDefinedAt(a.asInstanceOf[B]) }
```

So my problem is the isDefinedAt method. I have to check if A is an instance of B at runtime. 
a.isInstanceOf[B] doesn't work due to type erasure.

I tried to use TypeTag/ClassTag and for B that works just fine, but the Type for A ist always Any.

So, how can I check if A is an instance of B?

**Update:** I use it in this code:

```
  def map[A](f: Id ~> Id, x: A): A =
    {
      val y = x match {
        //many matches more on my own data structures
        case l : List[_] => l.map(map(f,_))
        case m : Map[_,_] => m.map(map(f,_))
        case (a,b) => (map(f,a),map(f,b))
        case a => a
      }
      if (f.isDefinedAt(y))
        f(y).asInstanceOf[A]
      else
        y.asInstanceOf[A]
    }
```

If I use the ~> directly everything works fine with typeTag[A].tpe <:< typeTag[B].tpe.

But if I use it with this map function, typeTag[A].tpe is always Any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are okay with modifying the signature of isDefinedAt to take a TypeTag, you can implement pft this way:

```
  type Id[A] = A
  trait ~>[F[_], G[_]] {
    def apply[A](a: F[A]): G[A]
    def isDefinedAt[A: TypeTag](a: A): Boolean
  }

  implicit def pft[B: TypeTag](f: PartialFunction[B, B]) = new (Id ~> Id) {
    def apply[A](a: A): A = f(a.asInstanceOf[B]).asInstanceOf[A]
    def isDefinedAt[A: TypeTag](a: A): Boolean =
      typeTag[A].tpe =:= typeTag[B].tpe && f.isDefinedAt(a.asInstanceOf[B])
  }
```

This solution gets a [TypeTag](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.reflect.api.TypeTags$TypeTag) for both `B` and `A` and verifies that they are the same type before delegating to the partial function's `isDefinedAt` method.  For more information on type tags, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232195/547212).

For example:

```
val halfEven: PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case n if n % 2 == 0 => n / 2
}

val halfEvenT: Id ~> Id = halfEven

halfEvenT.isDefinedAt(1) // false
halfEvenT.isDefinedAt(2) // true
halfEvenT.isDefinedAt("test") // false
```

More generically, you could define a constrained partial transformation as taking an additional higher kinded type that constrains `A`:

```
  trait ConstrainedPartialTransformation[F[_], G[_], C[_]] {
    def apply[A: C](a: F[A]): G[A]
    def isDefinedAt[A: C](a: A): Boolean
  }

  implicit def cpft[B: TypeTag](f: PartialFunction[B, B]) = new ConstrainedPartialTransformation[Id, Id, TypeTag] {
    def apply[A: TypeTag](a: A) = f(a.asInstanceOf[B]).asInstanceOf[A]
    def isDefinedAt[A: TypeTag](a: A) =
      typeTag[A].tpe =:= typeTag[B].tpe && f.isDefinedAt(a.asInstanceOf[B])
  }
```

This is similar to how Scalaz 7 supports natural transformations where there is a context bound on A.  See [ConstrainedNaturalTransformation](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/NaturalTransformation.scala#L56) from Scalaz 7.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I see now, that I stated the question to simple. My problem lies also with how I use this transformation.
I tried basically the same as your first solution and got typeTag[A].tpe = Any with my code. I will update my question shortly.
I don't now how to use your second solution probably(No TypeTag available for Int)

Comment: Ah, I see.  The reason Any is getting inferred is that the compiler doesn't have any information about List or Map's type params in the body of the map function.

Comment: Consider the partial function: `val pf: PartialFunction[List[Int], List[Int]] = { case l => l.reverse }`.  What should `map` do with this example? It looks like the map function is assuming that the `~>` passed to it is defined for a type that does not take params.  I can get `map` to work under that assumption but I wonder if the problem should be tackled differently? Maybe restate what you are trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying do write a generic map function for an AST.
Example: Transform one AST to another where all identifiers are renamed. A little bit like term rewriting in Kiama, which I unfortunately can't use.

Comment: Thanks to your hint with List or Map's type params I got it working, because I know at every point what kind of Map or List I'm using map on :). Also I added map[A: TypeTag](...), and test if f is defined on x instead of y. Thank you!