# Pattern matching doesn't work

Tags: scala

I wonder, why doesn't this work:

```
  def example(list: List[Int]) = list match {
    case Nil => println("Nil")
    case List(x) => println(x)
  }                                             

  example(List(11, 3, -5, 5, 889, 955, 1024))
```

It says:

```
scala.MatchError: List(11, 3, -5, 5, 889, 955, 1024) (of class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It doesn't work because `List(x)` means a list with exactly one element. Check it:

```
def example(list: List[Int]) = list match {
  case Nil => println("Nil")
  case List(x) => println("one element: " + x)
  case xs => println("more elements: " + xs)
} 

example(List(11, 3, -5, 5, 889, 955, 1024))
//more elements: List(11, 3, -5, 5, 889, 955, 1024) 
example(List(5))
//one element: 5
```

Comment: xs could be of any type. how do I catch xs of type List[Int] exactly?

Comment: It's common problem in scala, helpful link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 5):

Because `List(x)` only matches lists with one element. So

```
def example(list: List[Int]) = list match {
  case Nil => println("Nil")
  case List(x) => println(x)
}
```

only works with lists of zero or one element.

Answer (score 3):

As other posters have pointed out, `List(x)` only matches a list of 1 element.

There is however syntax for matching multiple elements:

```
def example(list: List[Int]) = list match {
  case Nil => println("Nil")
  case List(x @ _*) => println(x)
}                                             

example(List(11, 3, -5, 5, 889, 955, 1024)) // Prints List(11, 3, -5, 5, 889, 955, 1024)
```

It's the funny `@ _*` thing that makes the difference. `_*` matches a repeated parameter, and `x @` says "bind this to `x`".

The same works with any pattern match that can match repeated elements (e.g, `Array(x @ _*)` or `Seq(x @ _*)`). `List(x @ _*)` can also match empty lists, although in this case, we've already matched Nil.

You can also use `_*` to match "the rest", as in:

```
def example(list: List[Int]) = list match {
  case Nil => println("Nil")
  case List(x) => println(x)
  case List(x, xs @ _*) => println(x + " and then " + xs)
}
```

Comment: @Grienders Could you elaborate? What would you like to know about (x::xs)?