# On subclass instance handling

Tags: scala, subclass

Suppose I have a trait `A` and a class `A1` that extends `A`:

```
trait A
class A1 extends A
```

and `A1` has some unique property:

```
class A1 extends A { val hello = "hello" }
```

and I have a method that I want to handle all subclasses of trait `A`:

```
def handle:A = new A1
```

but, if I try to access unique properties defined in A1, understandably, it doesn't work:

```
scala> handle.hello
<console>:11: error: value hello is not a member of A
              handle.hello
                     ^
```

Once I'm done handling instances of subclasses of `A` as `A`s, how do I once again access them with all their unique properties? How does this mechanism work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are various mechanisms of varying complexity available to deal with this, but possibly the easiest and most common would be pattern matching:

```
val a = get
...do stuff with a as an `A`...
a match {
  case a1: A1 => a1.hello
  ...other case clauses for other subtypes of A, if required...
  case _ => println("Not a known sub-type of A")
}
```

Another mechanism involves `ClassTag`s and/or `TypeTag`s (or `Manifest`s, pre Scala 2.10 or so), with which I am less familiar.

Comment: I'll look around for articles on `ClassTag`s and `TypeTag`s. Any suggestions maybe?

Comment: Try [here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-2-10-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it).

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible mechanisms is to define additional interfaces as traits. For example:

```
scala> class A
defined class A

scala> trait A1 { val hello = "hello" }
defined trait A1

scala> def handle:A with A1 = new A() with A1
handle: A with A1

scala> handle.hello
res0: String = hello
```

Comment: How does this help in a generic method handling subclasses of A? It isn't known at compile time if the instance of `A` is also `A with A1`, to find that out you need pattern matching or casting.