# Pattern matching on generic type in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, reflection, pattern-matching, erasure

I have scala function that looks like this:

Now, depending upon the type of T (In my case, it can be `Double`, `Boolean` and `LocalDate`),
I need to apply functions on `ob`. Something like this (I know the code will make no sense but I am trying to convey what I mean to do):

```
def X[T](ob: Observable[T]): Observable[T] = {
    //code  
    T match {
    case Double => DoSomething1(ob:Observable[Double]):Observable[Double]
    case Boolean => DoSomething2(ob:Observable[Boolean]):Observable[Boolean]
    case LocalDate => DoSomething3(ob:Observable[LocalDate]):Observable[LocalDate]
    }
}
```

Taking into consideration the Erasure property of Scala, can reflection be somehow used to get the job done? Is it even possible?

Comment: Where `t: T` (e.g. variable you're matching against) comes from?

Comment: @om-nom-nom  I hope the edit makes it clear

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete ?

Comment: @om-nom-nom So, what do you suggest I do in my case?

Comment: This sounds more like something you could solve with inheritance and polymorphism. You can use regular overloading or subclassing. If nothing else look at cake pattern and finally magnet pattern. With magnet pattern you can pick your implementation flexibly. I don't know exactly what you are trying to do, so I can't give more concrete example. http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I would go with TypeTag if you're on 2.10+

```
import reflect.runtime.universe._

class Observable[Foo]

def X[T: TypeTag](ob: Observable[T]) = ob match {
    case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Double]   => println("Double obs")
    case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Boolean]  => println("Boolean obs")
    case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Int]      => println("Int obs")
}

X(new Observable[Int])
// Int obs
```

See also [this lengthy, but awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232195/298389)

Note also that I only took a glimpse at scala reflection, so likely somebody may write a better example of TypeTag usage.

Comment: It should be noted that pattern matching on `ob` is redundant in this case, as it's all based on if-else logic and `x` doesn't change type.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov yeah, I'm in a midway between simplified code and op's example where he used `ob` in `DoSomething(ob)`-like methods.

Comment: So there's no `compile-time` way to match on `T`'s type? In other words, this answer is *the* answer - there's no other way?

Comment: @KevinMeredith I think so. There is a "Ways to Pattern Match Generic Types in Scala" blog post that provides more insight and alternatives: http://www.cakesolutions.net/teamblogs/ways-to-pattern-match-generic-types-in-scala

Comment: Now "Ways to Pattern Match Generic Types in Scala" blog post can be found here: https://lepovirta.org/posts/2016-05-31-ways-to-pattern-match-generic-types-in-scala.html or https://gist.github.com/jkpl/5279ee05cca8cc1ec452fc26ace5b68b