# Pattern matching in Scala with case classes

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

I'm designing a model for remote storages and ended up with:

```
sealed trait StorageTag
case object Gcs extends StorageTag
case object S3 extends StorageTag

sealed trait StorageFile[T <: StorageTag]
final case class GcsFile(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[Gcs.type]
final case class S3File(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[S3.type]

sealed trait StorageConfig[T <: StorageTag]
final case class GcsConfig(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[Gcs.type]
final case class S3Config(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[S3.type]

def open[T <: StorageTag](storageFile: StorageFile[T], storageConfig: StorageConfig[T]): OutputStream =
  (storageFile, storageConfig) match {
    case (f: S3File, c: S3Config) => //
    case (f: GcsFile, c: GcsConfig) => //
  }
```

But Scala compiler complains with the following warning:

```
Warning:(39, 5) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following inputs: (GcsFile(_, _), S3Config(_)), (S3File(_, _), GcsConfig(_))
    (storageFile, storageConfig) match {
```

But in my specific case it is obviously a non-sense to open `S3File` with `GcsConfig` and vice versa. Is there a way to enhance the model?

I personally don't like the idea of throwing exception or leaving it as `MatchError` in those unreal cases like `GcsFile` with `S3Config`.

Comment: What is the use of `StorageTag` ? I see you are not using it at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give to compiler some information about what pairs are allowed. By passing pair `storageFile: StorageFile[T], storageConfig: StorageConfig[T]` to `open` method you are always in risk that someone calls `open` method with a wrong par and you will have to handle the exceptional case. To make it works in a type-safe way, you need to pass predefined type that "knows" what pairs are allowed.

For example like this:

```
sealed trait StorageTag
case object Gcs extends StorageTag
case object S3 extends StorageTag

sealed trait StorageFile[T <: StorageTag]
final case class GcsFile(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[Gcs.type]
final case class S3File(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[S3.type]

sealed trait StorageConfig[T <: StorageTag]
final case class GcsConfig(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[Gcs.type]
final case class S3Config(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[S3.type]

sealed trait FileConfPair
case class S3Conf(f: S3File, c: S3Config) extends FileConfPair
case class ScsConf(f: GcsFile, c: GcsConfig) extends FileConfPair

def open[T <: StorageTag](fp: FileConfPair): OutputStream =
  fp match {
    case S3Conf(f: S3File, c: S3Config) => ???
    case ScsConf(f: GcsFile, c: GcsConfig) => ???
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The Scala compiler complains and it is right, you are not covering all the possibilities. I think that you have 2 options.

1 Pattern match based on the generic type (as in this question: [Pattern matching on generic type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285235/pattern-matching-on-generic-type-in-scala))

```
def open[T <: StorageTag](storageFile: StorageFile[T], storageConfig: StorageConfig[T]): OutputStream =
  (storageFile, storageConfig) match {
    case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[Gcs]  => //
    case x if typeOf[T] <:< typeOf[S3]   => //
  }
```

2 The easiest one is to extract the logic to 2 Service classes as points @Bogdan Vakulenko

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest another way of solving this problem.
For what I understand of you model, what you really need is to identify which remote storage you have to execute the correct `open` *logic*.
Thus, you can just provide implicit evidence of that, for example like this:

```
sealed trait StorageTag extends Product with Serializable
implicit case object Gcs extends StorageTag
implicit case object S3 extends StorageTag

sealed trait StorageFile[T <: StorageTag] extends Product with Serializable { 
  def bucket: String
  def path: String
}
final case class GcsFile(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[Gcs.type]
final case class S3File(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[S3.type]

sealed trait StorageConfig[T <: StorageTag] extends Product with Serializable {
  def keyPath: String
}
final case class GcsConfig(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[Gcs.type]
final case class S3Config(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[S3.type]

def open[T <: StorageTag](storageFile: StorageFile[T], storageConfig: StorageConfig[T])
                         (implicit tag: T):String = tag match {
  case S3  =>
    s"S3 -> bucket: '${storageFile.bucket}', path: '${storageFile.path}' | config keyPath: '${storageConfig.keyPath}'"
  case Gcs =>
    s"Gcs -> bucket: '${storageFile.bucket}', path: '${storageFile.path}' | config keyPath: '${storageConfig.keyPath}'"
  }
```

Now, you can call the method this way

```
open(S3File(bucket = "bucket", path = "path"), S3Config(keyPath = "keyPath"))
// res0: String = "S3 -> bucket: 'bucket', path: 'path' | config keyPath: 'keyPath'"

open(GcsFile(bucket = "bucket", path = "path"), GcsConfig(keyPath = "keyPath"))
// res1: String = "Gcs -> bucket: 'bucket', path: 'path' | config keyPath: 'keyPath'"

open(S3File(bucket = "bucket", path = "path"), GcsConfig(keyPath = "keyPath"))
// Compile time error!
```

Note that this approach would only work if all `StorageFiles` and `StorageConfigs` have the same properties.
If that is not the case you can try something like the following:
***However, note that this code is not completely typesafe, and may be tricked***

```
sealed trait StorageTag extends Product with Serializable
implicit case object Gcs extends StorageTag
implicit case object S3 extends StorageTag

sealed trait StorageFile[T <: StorageTag] extends Product with Serializable
final case class GcsFile(bucket: String, path: String, id: Int) extends StorageFile[Gcs.type]
final case class S3File(bucket: String, path: String) extends StorageFile[S3.type]

sealed trait StorageConfig[T <: StorageTag] extends Product with Serializable
final case class GcsConfig(keyPath: String, name: String) extends StorageConfig[Gcs.type]
final case class S3Config(keyPath: String) extends StorageConfig[S3.type]

def open[T <: StorageTag](storageFile: StorageFile[T], storageConfig: StorageConfig[T])
                         (implicit tag: T): String = tag match {
  case S3 =>
    // These lines are not checked in compile-time, you can put GcsFile instead, and it will compile and fail at run-time!!!
    val S3File(bucket, path) = storageFile
    val S3Config(keyPath) = storageConfig
    s"S3 -> bucket: '${bucket}', path: '${path}' | config keyPath: '${keyPath}'"
  case Gcs =>
    val GcsFile(bucket, path, id) = storageFile
    val GcsConfig(keyPath, name) = storageConfig
    s"Gcs -> bucket: '${bucket}', path: '${path}', id: $id | config keyPath: '${keyPath}', name: 'name'"
}

open(S3File(bucket = "bucket", path = "path"), S3Config(keyPath = "keyPath"))
// res0: String = "S3 -> bucket: 'bucket', path: 'path' | config keyPath: 'keyPath'"

open(GcsFile(bucket = "bucket", path = "path", id = 0), GcsConfig(keyPath = "keyPath", name = "name"))
// res1: String = "Gcs -> bucket: 'bucket', path: 'path', id: 0 | config keyPath: 'keyPath', name: 'name'"

open(S3File(bucket = "bucket", path = "path"), GcsConfig(keyPath = "keyPath", name = "name"))
// Compile time error!

open(
  GcsFile(bucket = "bucket", path = "path", id = 0).asInstanceOf[StorageFile[StorageTag]],
  GcsConfig(keyPath = "keyPath", name = "name").asInstanceOf[StorageConfig[StorageTag]]
)(S3.asInstanceOf[StorageTag])
// Runtime error!!!!!!!
```