# Type mismatch generics with classOf Scala

Tags: scala, generics, types

I have a method that should dynamically cast a field member into a certain type depending on a configuration flag `format`.

This flag `format`, accepts one of the following type values:

```
object Types {
    val Str = "string"
    val IntNum1 = "int"
    val IntNum2 = "integer"
    val DoubleNum = "double"
    val LongNum = "long"
}
```

One option would be to use reflection. Another option would be to use pattern matching (the method I'm trying to do this with)

Here's the method for `String` types:

```
private def getValClassIfStr(format: String): Class[String] = {
    format.toLowerCase match {
        case Types.Str => classOf[String]
        case _ => null
    }
}
```

And Here's the method for Numerical types, extending from `AnyVal`, that fails to compile:

```
private def getValueClass[T <: AnyVal](format: String): Try[Class[T]] = {
    format.toLowerCase match {
        case Types.IntNum1 || Types.IntNum2 => Success(classOf[Int])
        case Types.DoubleNum => Success(classOf[Double])
        case Types.LongNum => Success(classOf[Long])
        case _ => Failure(new Exception)
    }
}
```

The second method doesn't compile because of a: 
`Type mismatch: required Try[Class[T]] found Try[Class[Int]]`

Which I don't understand, given `T <: AnyVal`.

Any idea? and if that's a bad approach, what would a "clean" alternative be?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56822188/using-same-type-parameter-as-argument-type-and-parameter-type-with-match-express
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21285235/pattern-matching-on-generic-type-in-scala

Comment: I would just create my own **ADT** of types and my own parser.

Comment: @Mehdi B. : What will happen if someone calls `getValueClass[Double]("int")` ? `Type mismatch` error is because of this. Compiler does not believe that actual return type will conform to declared return type.

Comment: @asanand Thanks, that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason why this doesn't work becomes clearer once you replace `Class[T]` in the return value with `Class[AnyVal]`:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Class[Int](classOf[scala.Int])
 required: Class[AnyVal]
Note: Int <: AnyVal, but Java-defined class Class is invariant in type T.
You may wish to investigate a wildcard type such as `_ <: AnyVal`. (SLS 3.2.10)
```

In other words, any call to `getValueClass[T]` would always have to be populated with `T = AnyVal` by the compiler, since `format` is only evaluated at runtime. This, however, is not possible since `Class[T]` is invariant, so you can't return a `Class[Int]` and a `Class[Double]` as a `Class[AnyVal]`, since for invariant containers there's no subtyping relationship.

To demonstrate:

```
var x: Class[AnyVal] = _
x = classOf[Int]
// Boom
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was helpful.