# Extract class from Option[T] when in None clause

Tags: scala, reflection, manifest, option-type

Assuming you have the following code

```
  trait T {

  }

  case class First(int:Int) extends T
  case class Second(int:Int) extends T

  val a:Option[T] = Option(First(3))

  val b:Option[Second] = None

  def test[A](a:Option[A])(implicit manifest:Manifest[Option[A]]) = {
    a match {
      case Some(z) => println("we have a value here")
      case None => a match {
        case t:Option[First] => println("instance of first class")
        case s:Option[Second] => println("instance of second class")
      }
    }
  }

  test(b)
```

How would you extract what `type` the enclosing `A` is if the option happens to be a None. I have attempted to do various combinations of manifests, but none of them seem to work, each time it complains about the types being eliminated with erasure, i.e.

```
non-variable type argument First in type pattern Option[First] is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
```

Comment: Have you tried `Manifest[A]` (or tag equivalent) instead of the current implicit argument? So that you could use this meta data about `A` type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [type tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it), a modern replacement for Manifest:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

trait T
case class First(int:Int) extends T
case class Second(int:Int) extends T

def test[A: TypeTag](a: Option[A]) = {
  a match {
    case Some(_) => println("we have a value here")
    case None => typeOf[A] match {
      case t if t =:= typeOf[First] => println("instance of First")
      case t if t =:= typeOf[Second] => println("instance of Second")
      case t => println(s"unexpected type $t")
    }
  }
}
```

Example

```
val a = Option(First(3)) // we have a value here
val b: Option[First] = None // instance of First
val c: Option[Second] = None // instance of Second
val d: Option[Int] = None // unexpected type Int
```

---

By the way, you are interested in the type of `A` (which is being eliminated by erasure), so even with manifests you need one on `A` and not on `Option[A]`.