# How to determine type of Seq[A] without Reflection API

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Is it possible to determine type of `Seq[A]` in Scala 2.11.2?

For example:

```
val fruit = List("apples", "oranges", "pears")
val nums = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

I want to print type of Seq something like this:

```
scala> def printType[A](xs: Seq[A]): Unit = xs match {
     | case x: List[String] => println("String")
     | case y: List[Int] => println("Int")
     | }

<console>:8: warning: non-variable type argument String in type pattern List[Str
ing] (the underlying of List[String]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by era
sure
       case x: List[String] => println("String")
               ^
<console>:9: warning: non-variable type argument Int in type pattern List[Int] (
the underlying of List[Int]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
       case y: List[Int] => println("Int")
               ^
<console>:9: warning: unreachable code
       case y: List[Int] => println("Int")
                                   ^
printType: [A](xs: Seq[A])Unit
```

p.s. I'm new in Scala.

**UPDATE:**

Is there solution without using Reflection API?

Answer (score 0):

you could use type tags, see the accepted answer to this question for a detailed example similar to your own: [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641)

Comment: please, don't answer just linking to other answers. Either mark the question as duplicate or comment.

Comment: Apologies, but neither seemed appropriate. I didn't think they were duplicates since the linked question is asking for an example of using type tags. My answer to his question was "You could use TypeTags" the link is a reference which provides a solid example and happens to be an SO answer.

Comment: link-only answer are discouraged in any case: the answer should be valuable by itself and links should only provide additional references. If you don't think it's a duplicate then please write down a solution yourself and use the link as a reference.