# Scala type filtering

Tags: scala

I wanted to make an algorithm that filters elements by type

I did something like that

```
trait Valor
case class A() extends Valor
case class B() extends Valor
case class C() extends Valor

val list : List[Valor] = List(
  A(), A(),
  B(), B(), B(),
  C()
)
def getOfType[T](list: List[_]) = {
  list.filter {
    case _ : T => true
    case _ => false
  }
}
getOfType[A](list)
```

But the output of it is

> List[Any] = List(A(), A(), B(), B(), B(), C())

I'd understand if it wouldn't compile at all. But why does it compile and give such strange result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the `: T` is eliminated by erasure (there's a warning) since the generic aspect is lost after compilation, meaning that there's no way for it to check the generic type at runtime.  So basically it's not doing a check at all.  The parameter is a list of anything (`List[_]`), and the filter doesn't filter at all, so it's producing a list of anything.

Comment: But shouldn't that be considered a compile time bug?

Comment: I would call it a "bug", but the compiler doesn't produce errors for erasure-related things, it just issues warnings.  It's probably a warning you should take seriously, since it's still a bug it your code, but the compiler authors didn't want them to be compiler errors.

Answer (score 4):

(If you are interested in possible solution; does not fit in comment)

---

First, we need some imports

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
```

Then we can tell the compiler to generate a [`ClassTag`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html) for the type parameter `T` at compile-time.
Using this `ClassTag` we can compare the desired class with the class of each element.

```
def getOfType[T](list: List[_])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): List[_] = {
  list.filter { elem => tag.runtimeClass.equals(elem.getClass) }
}
```

Now, we can go even further and return a List of `T`s instead of a List of `Any`

```
def getOfType[T](list: List[_])(implicit tag: ClassTag[T]): List[T] = {
  list.collect {
    case elem if tag.runtimeClass.equals(elem.getClass) => elem.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

Interestingly, pattern matching on the type *magically* works after introducing the implicit `ClassTag` evidence, which lets us simplify things a lot

```
def getOfType[T : ClassTag](list: List[_]): List[T] = {
  list.collect {
    case elem : T => elem
  }
}
```

This works for these simple classes `A`, `B` & `C`. However, if you want to filter out polymorphic classes like `List[String]`, you will need to use [`TypeTag`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12232195/3041008). You can have a look at this [example gist](https://gist.github.com/mucaho/49f785ce26af70e5c1e1) which demonstrates polymorphic type filtering.

---

We could probably add an additional, explicit `Class[T]` argument to the function instead, which we could use to do the comparison with.

Comment: But is it efficient? I've heard that using Class Tags is like using Reflection. "Should be avoided by all means"

Comment: @KrzysztofWende To be frank, I could not find any specific documentation on what is computed at compile-time and what is computed at run-time w/ reflection (despite tags being added at compile-time). Do you have links to share on this manner?