# WeakTypeTag v. TypeTag

Tags: scala

In the REPL, I'm writing out the examples from [Reflection - TypeTags and Manifests](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html).

I'm confused by the difference between `WeakTypeTag` and `TypeTag`.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
```

**TypeTag**

```
scala> def paramInfo[T](x: T)(implicit tag: TypeTag[T]): Unit = {
     |   val targs = tag.tpe match {  case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
     |   println(s"type tag of $x has type arguments $targs")
     | }
paramInfo: [T](x: T)(implicit tag: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])Unit
```

**WeakTypeTag**

```
scala> def weakParamInfo[T](x: T)(implicit tag: WeakTypeTag[T]): Unit = {
     |   val targs = tag.tpe match { case TypeRef(_, _, args) => args }
     |    println(s"type tag of $x has type arguments $targs")
     | }
weakParamInfo: [T](x: T)(implicit tag: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[T])Unit
```

**Running a Simple, Non-exhaustive Example**

```
scala> paramInfo2(List(1,2,3))
type of List(1, 2, 3) has type arguments List(Int)

scala> weakParamInfo(List(1,2,3)
     | )
type tag of List(1, 2, 3) has type arguments List(Int)
```

What's the difference between them?

Comment: This is answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it but not with the best example

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`TypeTag` guarantees that you have a concrete type (i.e. one which doesn't contain any type parameters or abstract type members); `WeakTypeTag` does not.

```
scala> import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

scala> def foo[T] = typeTag[T]
<console>:10: error: No TypeTag available for T
       def foo[T] = typeTag[T]
                           ^

scala> def foo[T] = weakTypeTag[T]
foo: [T]=> reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[T]
```

But of course it can't actually get you the generic parameters the method is called with when used like this:

```
scala> foo[Int]
res0: reflect.runtime.universe.WeakTypeTag[Int] = WeakTypeTag[T]
```

You can only build a `TypeTag` of a generic type if you have `TypeTag`s for all parameters:

```
scala> def foo[T: TypeTag] = typeTag[List[T]]
foo: [T](implicit evidence$1: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T])reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[List[T]]
```

If you have a `WeakTypeTag` of a concrete type, it should behave the same as a `TypeTag` (as far as I know).