# Scala Pattern Matching on Different type of Seq

Tags: scala

I have 3 functions, `kk expect Array[Byte]` or `List[Array[Byte]]`, So I did a pattern matching,

```
def gg (a :Array[Byte]) = "w"
def ff (a :List[Array[Byte]]) = "f"

def kk(datum : Any) = datum match {
  case w : Array[Byte] => gg(w)
  case f :List[Array[Byte]] => ff(f)
  case _ => throw new Exception("bad data")
}
```

and I get an error when I try to compile the code:

> non-variable type argument List[Any] in type pattern List[List[Any]] (the underlying of List[List[Any]]) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure

so instead I construct my `kk` function as flowing and it can be compiled now:

```
def kk(datum : Any) = datum match {
  case w : Array[Byte] => gg(w)
  case f :List[_] => ff(f.asInstanceOf[List[Array[Byte]]])
  case _ => throw new Exception("bad data")}
```

My questions:
1: is my current version of `kk` is idiomatic way to do a pattern matching for List, if not can someone show to how to do it?

2: say if I want to pattern matching `List[Any]` and `List[List[Any]]`, how am able to do that? `(ff(f.asInstanceOf[List[Array[Byte]]])` may cause an error if I datum is type of `List[Byte]`)

Comment: Thanks for you post, I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it would be an good place as well.

Comment: after reading, the new code should be looks like:  def gg (a :Array[Byte]) = "w"

  def ff (a :List[Array[Byte]]) = "f"

  def binaryDecodexx[A : TypeTag](datum : A) = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Array[Byte]] => gg(datum.asInstanceOf[Array[Byte]])
    case t if t =:= typeOf[List[Array[Byte]]] => ff(datum.asInstanceOf[List[Array[Byte]]])
      // case w : Array[Byte] => gg(w)
      // case f :List[_] =>
  }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is several things to be said:

1. Type erasure is sometimes heavy thing to deal with. Try to gain your insight in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1094173/how-do-i-get-around-type-erasure-on-scala-or-why-cant-i-get-the-type-paramete)
2. Need for function like that is probably caused by bad design somewhere else. `T` and `List[T]` are rarely used as alternatives. If it is your case, try bring them to at least [`Either`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.Either)'s or more specific case classes.
3. If you are really have `Any` without any other prearranged knowledge and you really have the need of certainty it's `List[Byte]` or `List[List[Byte]]` your only option is to check every element of collection like this:

   ```
   class ListMatch[A](f: Any => Option[A]) {
     def unapply(obj: Any) = obj match {
       case seq: List[_] =>
         seq.foldLeft[Option[List[A]]](Some(Nil)) {
           (optSeq, elem) => for {
             seq <- optSeq
             elem <- f(elem)
           } yield elem :: seq
         } map (_.reverse)
       case _ => None
     }
   }

   val matchByte: PartialFunction[Any, Byte] = {
     case b: Byte => b
   }

   val ByteList = new ListMatch(matchByte.lift)
   val ByteListList = new ListMatch(ByteList.unapply)
   ```

   so you definition changes to

   ```
   def kk(datum: Any) = datum match {
     case ByteList(w) => gg(w)
     case ByteListList(f) => ff(f)
     case _ => "bad data"
   }
   ```

   you could try following tests to ensure correctness:

   ```
   kk(1)  // bad data
   kk(List(1.toByte)) // w
   kk(List(List(1.toByte))) // f
   kk(List(1.toByte, 2)) // bad data
   kk(List(1.toByte), List(2)) // bad data
   ```