# Scala pattern matching error in generic function

Tags: scala, generics

I have written a generic function to get a value from a HashMap[String, AnyVal]. This method returns a value from the name but also has a functionality to make sure it is of a specific type:

```
class Context {
  private var variables = HashMap[String, Any] ()

  def getVariable (name: String):Any = variables(name)
  def setVariable (name: String, value: Any) = variables += ((name, value))

  def getVariableOfType[T <: AnyVal] (name:String):T ={
    val v = variables(name)
    v match {
      case T => v.asInstanceOf[T]
      case _ => null.asInstanceOf[T]
    }
  }

}
```

The function getVariableOfType[T <: AnyVal] will not compile because it says "Cannot resolve symbol T" at the line case `T => v.asInstanceOf[T]`

Comment: To make it compile, you probably meant: `case something: T => v.asInstanceOf[T] /*or better just: something */`. Though it is not recommended, you should use [`TypeTag`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/typetags-manifests.html)s.

Comment: @GáborBakos I am trying to match by type but I will try that thanks

Comment: In that case you definitely should use type tags. Otherwise -because of erasure- it will always go on the first `case`.

Comment: Besides what @Gábor says which is why your solution doesn't work, the compiler error is because you're  match is wrong. It should be: `v match {   case _ : T =>  v.asInstanceOf[T]}`, otherwise the compiler tries to match `v` to an already defined value called `T`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it) explains type tags even better than the official documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply having `case x: T => v.asInstanceOf[T]` will match any type because of erasure. To really do the type checking you have to make a `ClassTag` available for `T`: `[T <: AnyVal : ClassTag]`.

Here is a working definition of `getVariableOfType`:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

def getVariableOfType[T <: AnyVal : ClassTag] (name:String):T ={
  val v = variables(name)
  v match {
    case x: T => x
    case _ => null.asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}
```

The downside is that `ClassTag` doesn't completely remove the issue of erasure. So requesting for example a `Seq[Int]`, will actually match on every type of sequence (`Seq[Double]`, `Seq[String]`, etc.). In your example `T` is a subtype of `AnyVal`, so this won't be an issue.