# How to get a Scala runtime class with generic parameters?

Tags: scala

I wonder if it is possible to do something like the following:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class Bar[T]
def foo[T]()(implicit ctag: reflect.ClassTag[T]) { 
  val clazz = classOf[Bar[ctag.runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]]] 
}
```

Here the Scala compiler complains:

```
error: stable identifier required, but ctag.runtimeClass found.
```

Is there a way to get the class type with type parameters inserted from the runtime type information available in the function?

Comment: Is this what you want to do: `def foo[T]() = new Bar[T]`

Comment: No, I need the type (classOf[Bar[T]]), not an instance of the class.

Comment: Have you tried: `val clazz = classOf[Bar[T]]`

Comment: @Mr.V. Thanks, that actually does the trick. Would not have thought it to be this easy...

Comment: I still wonder why this works, because getting `classOf[T]` requires the ClassTag magic to work.

Comment: `def foo[T]() { val clazz = classOf[T] }`will throw `error: class type required but T found`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to get the class type with type parameters inserted from the runtime type information available in the function?

`classOf[Bar[T]]` works for a very simple reason: it *doesn't* insert any runtime information! `classOf[Bar[T]]`, `classOf[Bar[String]]`, `classOf[Bar[Int]]`, `classOf[Bar[_]]` are all the same; that's what type erasure means in JVM context (to avoid misleading, I prefer always using `classOf[Bar[_]]` where possible). Note that there is actually a single exception: if `Bar` is `Array`, because `classOf[Array[Int]]` and `classOf[Array[Object]]` (e.g.) are different!

`classOf[T]` obviously would need runtime information and so it doesn't work.

Comment: In addition to this helpful answer, I suggest reading http://stackoverflow.com/a/12232195/409976.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment by @Mr. V I realized that its actually easier than I initially thought:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
class Bar[T]
def foo[T]() { 
  val clazz = classOf[Bar[T]] 
}
```