# Converting nested Scala type to Java types

Tags: java, scala

I'm currently dealing with the AWS Java SDK, which expects Java types.

I've been using `JavaConverters` to explicitly converts types like maps and lists to java. I've been running into more and more complex types and found myself having to map deep into lists which is becoming unwieldy.

My current issue is I have a `Map[String, List[String]]` converting the overall object to java is simple but I'm being hit by type erasure when pattern matching the list in the map.

```
val t = m.map{
    case (k, v: List[String]) => k -> v //type erasure so unreachable
}
```

I found a great explanation of Type Tags in Scala which is an elegant solution I'd like to implement. [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it)

I'm just unsure how I'm implement this into my pattern match.

I've implemented a method that looks like so

```
def isNestedMap[A : TypeTag](xs: A): Boolean = typeOf[A] match {
    case t if t =:= typeOf[Map[String, List[String]]] => true
    case t => false
}
```

And a new case `case (k, v) if isNestedMap(v) => k -> "beans"` but this always return false as my method is seeing types as an `Any`.

Any ideas how to surmount this? Or better yet a way of recursively convert deep lists or maps to their java equivalents?

Thanks all.

EDIT: The Map is actually a type of `Map[String, Any]` so I need to know the type of `Any` before I can convert it to Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: The Map is actually a type of Map[String, Any] so I need to know the type of Any before I can convert it to Java

`TypeTag`s are inserted by the compiler according to the static type, so when you call `isNestedMap(v)`, it'll see `v: Any` and insert `isNestedMap[Any](v)(typeTag[Any])`.

> Or better yet a way of recursively convert deep lists or maps to their java equivalents?

Something like

```
def deepAsJava(x: Any): Any = x match {
  case l: List[_] => l.map(deepAsJava).asJava
  case m: Map[_, _] => m.map { case (k, v) => (k, deepAsJava(v)) }.asJava
  case ... // other collections you want to support
  case x => x
}
```

You can split it into separate functions for `listDeepAsJava`, etc. to get better type signatures for each:

```
def deepAsJava(x: Any): Any = x match {
  case l: List[_] => listDeepAsJava(l)
  case m: Map[_, _] => mapDeepAsJava(m)
  case ... // other collections you want to support
  case x => x
}

def listDeepAsJava(x: List[Any]): java.util.List[Any] = l.map(deepAsJava).asJava
...
```

Comment: This is almost exactly the solution I'm looking for. The only issue is that the result is a type of `Any` and I'm having to manually cast this using `.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[java.util.Map[String, Any]]]` any ideas how I could perhaps do this implicitly? It feels like splitting the methods up like you mentioned, would allow this but when attempting this it complains about type mismatches when the method's signature is `listDeepAsJava(x: List[Any]): java.util.List[Any]`

Comment: Yes, that's why I suggested splitting up methods. Note that you still need to use `deepAsJava` inside: I've updated the answer to clarify. Of course, it still gets you only `java.util.List[Any]`. To get `java.util.List[java.util.Map[...]]` is going to be a lot more complicated.

Comment: Thanks so much for all your help. This was the eloquent solution I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you problem is really related to erasure or even needs to make use of type tags. Here is quick session on the REPL demonstrating one way to make the conversions:

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> List(1,2,3).asJava
res0: java.util.List[Int] = [1, 2, 3]

scala> Map(1 -> List(1),2 -> List(2))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2))

scala> res1.asJava
res2: java.util.Map[Int,List[Int]] = {1=List(1), 2=List(2)}

scala> res1.map{ case (l,r) => l -> r.asJava}.asJava
res3: java.util.Map[Int,java.util.List[Int]] = {1=[1], 2=[2]}

scala> res1.mapValues(_.asJava).asJava
res5: java.util.Map[Int,java.util.List[Int]] = {1=[1], 2=[2]}
```

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough in my original answer but the Map type is actually `Map[String, Any]` so `.asJava` isn't available when mapping :(

Comment: So type tag can't possibly help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Array` instead of `List`.

```
val m = Map[String, Array[String]]()
val t = m.map{
    case (k, v: Array[String]) => k -> v //no type erasure
}
```