# Ambiguous overloading: fix it or try something else?

Tags: scala, implicit, scala.js, scala.rx, scalatags

Background: I'm working on using [scala.js](http://www.scala-js.org/)/[scalatags](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scalatags) together with [scala.rx](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx). What I'm trying to achieve is binding values from html inputs to Rx `Var`s, using operator style. Here's what I'm up to:

```
implicit class BoundHtmlInput(input: Input) {
  def bindTextTo(v: Var[String]): Input = {
    input.oninput = { (e: dom.Event) => v() = input.value}
    input
  }

  def bindNumberTo(v: Var[Int]): Input = {
    input.oninput = {(e: dom.Event) => v() = input.valueAsNumber}
    input
  }

  def ~>[T](v: Var[T])(implicit ev: T =:= Int): Input =
     bindNumberTo(v.asInstanceOf[Var[Int]])

  def ~>[T](v: Var[T])(implicit ev: T =:= String): Input = 
     bindTextTo(v.asInstanceOf[Var[String]])
}
```

It works fine for the method calls, but fails for operator `~>` call. The error is following:

```
Error:(43, 70) ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method ~> in class BoundHtmlInput of type [T](v: rx.Var[T])(implicit ev: =:=[T,String])org.scalajs.dom.html.Input
and  method ~> in class BoundHtmlInput of type [T](v: rx.Var[T])(implicit ev: =:=[T,Int])org.scalajs.dom.html.Input
match argument types (rx.core.Var[String])
```

And I'm not happy about the usage of `asInstanceOf` either.

I hope this provides enough context. My question is, what is the better way to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using generalized type constraints here over plain old overloading? How about just `def ~>(v: Var[Int]): Input` and `def ~>(v: Var[String]): Input`?

Comment: Then I get: `double definition:
def ~>(v: rx.Var[Int]): org.scalajs.dom.html.Input at line 26 and
def ~>(v: rx.Var[String]): org.scalajs.dom.html.Input at line 27
have same type after erasure: (v: rx.core.Var)`

Comment: maybe make just one `~>` and use `TypeTags` as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it

Comment: There is a simple trick to workaround that: add a dummy implicit (just so that the signatures are different): `def ~>(v: Var[Int]): Input` and `def ~>(v: Var[String])(implicit d: DummyImplicit): Input`. If you have more overloads to define one of the other alternatives is to use the *Magnet Pattern* (google it). (EDIT: though you can still use several `DummyImplicit` params as sjrd has just suggested)

Comment: @Łukasz `TypeTags` use reflection, that is banned in `scala.js`

Comment: ow, thanks, didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Var[Int]` and `Var[String]` directly, with dummy implicits to fight off double-def-after-erasure:

```
def ~>[T](v: Var[Int]): Input =
  bindNumberTo(v)

def ~>[T](v: Var[String])(implicit dummy: DummyImplicit): Input = 
  bindTextTo(v)
```

You can add as many `DummyImplicit`s as necessary, if you have more types to deal with:

```
def ~>[T](v: Var[Boolean])(implicit dummy1: DummyImplicit,
    dummy2: DummyImplicit): Input = 
  bindBooleanTo(v)
```