# Scala: match case over generic functions

Tags: scala

Is it possible to do `match-case` over functions? 
I want to define a behavior for different types of functions. Say I have the following possibilities:

- `f: T => Int`
- `f: T => String`
- `f: T => Lis[Int]`
- `f: T => Boolean`
- `f: T => Double`
- ...

and for each of these options I have a function; for example for `Int` output: 

`def doThisForInt(f: T => Int) = {  ...  }`

and this for `Boolean` output: 
`
def doThisForBoolean(f: T => Boolean) = {  ...  }

So now suppose a function definition is given: `val f = (input: T) => true`.  We should choose the corresponding case to `f: T => Boolean`.

Note that all these functions differ in the output type. Alternatively, given `f` can I get the output type of this function?

Comment: What is your use-case? It sounds like type classes would be better suited for this, as a giant match/case is a code smell.

Comment: So like define a type for each of these cases? Like one for `f: T => Int`, one for `f: T => Double`, etc?

Comment: What is the signature for the method that you want to use the match? It wouldn't accept `T => Int` because you want it to be generic, right? Something like: `def doSomething[T, R](f: T => R): ??? = ???` ? What should be returned?

Answer (score 4):

[TypeTags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218641/scala-what-is-a-typetag-and-how-do-i-use-it) are what you are looking for:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def doThisForInt(f: T => Int) = ???

def printType[R: TypeTag](f: T => R) = typeOf[R] match {
  case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] =>
    val toInt: (T) => Int = f.asInstanceOf[T => Int]
    doThisForInt(toInt)
  case t if t =:= typeOf[Double] =>
    // ...
  case t if t =:= typeOf[List[Int]] =>
  // ...
}

printType((x: T) => 1) // int
printType((x: T) => 2.0) // double
printType((x: T) => List(2)) // list
```

As you can see, it is possible, but not very elegant and against [good practices](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#212-should-not-use-any-or-anyref-or-isinstanceof--asinstanceof).

Chains of instanceOf checks can often be replaced with virtual methods (see the [example](https://github.com/alexandru/scala-best-practices/blob/master/sections/2-language-rules.md#212-should-not-use-any-or-anyref-or-isinstanceof--asinstanceof)) and the result type of function can possibly be a type parameter. It's hard to give more advice without knowing more context for your use case.