# Type-parameterize a DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, streaming, apache-kafka, type-parameter

Can a `DStream` have `type parameter`s?

If yes, how?

When I try `lazy val qwe = mStream.mapWithState(stateSpec)` on `myDStream: DStream[(A, B)]` (class parameter), I get:

```
value mapWithState is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream[(A, B)]
    lazy val qwe = mStream.mapWithState(stateSpec)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substantial subset of the Spark API requires implicit `ClassTags` (see [Scala: What is a TypeTag and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12218641/6910411)) and `PairDStreamFunctions.mapWithState` is no different. Check [class definition](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f830bb9170f6b853565d9dd30ca7418b93a54fe3/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L37-L38):

```
class PairDStreamFunctions[K, V](self: DStream[(K, V)])
  (implicit kt: ClassTag[K], vt: ClassTag[V], ord: Ordering[K])
```

[and](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f830bb9170f6b853565d9dd30ca7418b93a54fe3/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/PairDStreamFunctions.scala#L380-L381):

```
def mapWithState[StateType: ClassTag, MappedType: ClassTag](
    spec: StateSpec[K, V, StateType, MappedType]
  ): MapWithStateDStream[K, V, StateType, MappedType] = {
  ...
}
```

If want to create a function which operates on a generic pair streams and uses `mapWithState` you should at least provide `ClassTags` for `KeyType` and `ValueType` types:

```
def foo[T : ClassTag, U : ClassTag](
  stream: DStream[(T, U)], f: StateSpec[T, U, Int, Int]) = stream.mapWithState(f)
```

If `StateType` and `MappedType` are parametrized as well you'll need `ClassTags` for these too:

```
def bar[T : ClassTag, U : ClassTag, V : ClassTag,  W : ClassTag](
  stream: DStream[(T, U)], f: StateSpec[T, U, V, W]) = stream.mapWithState(f)
```