# In scala 2.13, how to use actual TypeTag in macro?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-reflect, scala-2.13

This capability seems to be dropped by [SI-6186](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/6186), and no mechanism could be used to replace it

I found the following remarks in its commit message:

Now we restore the broken balance by banning TypeTag from macro impls.
This forces anyone to use AbsTypeTags, **and if someone wants to check the input
for presence of abstract types, it's possible to do that manually.**

What does "the presence of abstract types" and "do that manually" mean? Can someone give me a concrete example on these?

Comment: Not really helping on this one but keep in mind that `TypeTag` doesn't exist anymore in Scala 3 and macros in general are changing as well.

Comment: @GaëlJ yes I know, but this is a scala 2 question. Historically, the change happens to scala 2.11

Comment: @tribbloid Is it just out of curiousity or do you really need that? Why are current `TypeTag`s/`WeakTypeTag`s/`ClassTag`s from scala 2 reflect not enough for you?

Comment: @tribbloid  I guess `AbsTypeTag` existed in outdated version of Scala. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093752/scala-macros-cannot-create-typetag-from-a-type-t-having-unresolved-type-parame

Comment: @tribbloid How are you going to use `TypeTag`s rather than `WeakTypeTag`s in a macro?

Comment: @tribbloid `TypeTag[T]` is a subtype of `WeakTypeTag[T]`